# Maintaining pooled connction to Postgres DB via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am new to AWS API Gateway and i am currently exploring the options of moving the fast-api from ec2 to AWS API gateway. I was wondereing if someone could clarify how lambda would ssh into our db and maintaing the connection pool via API gateway.
Thanks

I did have a look at the API Gateway docs but could find anything releated.

Comment: API Gateway is an HTTP based gateway.  ssh or a direct connection using the PostgreSQL protocol would not be able to pass through it.

Comment: Ah okay, how would you reckon we get passed it ? Is there a service to manage our pooled connection to the db ?

Comment: Take a look at Amazon RDS Proxy - https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/ but be aware that it's not free.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar, I just had a look at RDS Proxy, but the aws account that i am using doesn't have access to the hosted db, what is another way of handling this .